# Integration of Products of Cosine

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Is there any elegant way of showing $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x)\cos(4x)\cos(5x)\cos(6x) = 0$$

More generally, how could one approach to show that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \prod_{k=1}^{N} \cos(k x) = 0$$ if any only if $N$ is congruent to $1$ or $2$ mod $4$? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hint: Shift $x$ by $\pi$ and use properties of odd/even functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $\cos [k(x-\pi)]=(-1)^k\cos kx$. This means that for $N=4l+2$, there are  $2l+1$ cosines $\cos kx$ for which, $k$ is odd. Also, for $N=4l+1$, there are  $4l+1$ cosines $\cos kx$ for which, $k$ is odd. Therefore, one can write
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \prod_{k=1}^{N} \cos(k x)dx
{=\int_{\pi}^{3\pi} \prod_{k=1}^{N} \cos(k x)dx
=
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \prod_{k=1}^{N} \cos(k [x-\pi])dx
\\=
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \prod_{k=1}^{N}(-1)^k \cos(k x)dx
=
\int_{0}^{2\pi} (-1)^\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\prod_{k=1}^{N} \cos(k x)dx.
}
$$
For $N=\text{$1$ or $2$}\mod 4$, $(-1)^\frac{N(N+1)}{2}=-1$ and for $N=\text{$0$ or $3$}\mod 4$, $(-1)^\frac{N(N+1)}{2}=1$, which proves the result.